# Is there any way to remove the option "Customer Access” from UI while sharing file attached to a record?

Tags: lightning-community, files, file-sharing

We don’t have either community or chatter enabled in our Org, but still seeing this option which will be misleading for the Users.

I looked at [salesforce help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_files_on_records_visible_to_customers.htm&type=5) but no luck so far!

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not something you can change as it's out of the box functionality. You'd have to create your own LWC or component to essentially hide that option. In your linked documentation, it clearly states:

> The customer access option is visible in the sharing detail of any
>   file shared with a record

[image]